# Dynamically calling attirb value from li class through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please help me in dynamically calling attrib value through jQuery from the 'li class' by identifying the 'itemprop'?

My HTML is as below,

```
<ul class="blockNoBordr">
  <li class="specHeading">Model</li>
  <li class="specText" itemprop="model">
    <span class="attribVal newattribVal">32LJ573D</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to dynamically call Model value into a JS code i.e., 32LJ573D

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript code showing what you've tried?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want the JS code to do with the value? You can retrieve the value by calling $(selector).text()

Comment: for example

`<h1 class="page-title">
        <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" itemprop="name">GO Bluetooth Speaker Black</span>    </h1>`

I used `jQuery('.page-title span[itemprop="name"]').text()` to dynamically call "GO Bluetooth Speaker Black"

Similarly, i want to dynamically call model value from class given in my description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log($('ul li[itemprop="model"].specText').first().text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="blockNoBordr">
  <li class="specHeading">Model</li>
  <li class="specText" itemprop="model">
    <span class="attribVal newattribVal">32LJ573D</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You need to pick li inside your ul with a specific class. The following code will work for you. I have printed text of li with class "specText" for reference. You could modify any attribute as per your requirement.

console.log($('ul li[itemprop="model"].specText').first().text());

Comment: multiple elements are returned in an array

Comment: `$('ul li.specHeading').text('model')`
I tried this as suggested, however it doesn't trigger me the desired value i.e., "32LJ573D"

Comment: we are close! I have multiple value with class specText

For eg:

`<ul class="blockNoBordr">
                <li class="specHeading">Brand Name</li>
                <li class="specText" itemprop="brand"><span class="attribVal newattribVal">LG</span></li>
            </ul>

<ul class="blockNoBordr">
                <li class="specHeading">Model</li>
                <li class="specText" itemprop="model"><span class="attribVal newattribVal">32LJ573D</span></li>
            </ul>`

I need to pick value by itemprop. Please assist

Comment: when I trigger this code in console **$('ul li.specText').text();** it is returning all the value in the given class i.e., LG232LJ573D

Comment: Yes, what do you want then? do you want first?

Comment: i want to have ONLY "32LJ573D" i.e., the model value

Comment: I want to use jQuery and call these values dynamically into my JS code

for eg:
var brand = "LG";
var Model = "32LJ573D";

Comment: you should use "console.log($('ul li[itemprop="model"].specText').first().text());"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @maverick

Comment: You should questions more clearly i.e. title should be "Dynamically calling l with certain class and attribute value through jQuery".. and give a demo to explain inputs clearly

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Will surely make a note of it. I do not have much knowledge on coding, for which I was not able to phrase the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose elements by classname, multiple elements are returned in an array. So choose the first element by adding index `[0]`.

```
 $('.classname')[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: It doesn't trigger the desired value, when i tried in console

Comment: It wouldn't trigger any value by itself. Use it in a function.